# What is correct mapped annotation for `JSON` in SQLAlchemy 2.x version?

Tags: python, json, sqlalchemy

The new version of SQLAlchemy introduced the ability to use type annotations using Mapped[Type] ([link](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/declarative_tables.html#using-annotated-declarative-table-type-annotated-forms-for-mapped-column)).

My question is, what should we use as an annotation for `sqlalchemy.types.JSON`? Is just `dict` will be ok?

I'm just using dict, but I want to understand the correct option for this.

Comment: It says in the documentation here: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/declarative_tables.html#mapped-column-derives-the-datatype-and-nullability-from-the-mapped-annotation

Answer (score 24):

You will need to first declare a mapping in your DeclarativeBase Type Annotation Map like this:

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase
from sqlalchemy.types import JSON
from typing import Any


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    type_annotation_map = {
        dict[str, Any]: JSON
    }
```

Note: This will also work for database specific json dialects, eg Postgres' `JSONB` type. For older versions of Python, you may need to do `from typing import Dict` and use that instead of using `dict` directly.

After doing so, you can use the above datatype in your table as so:

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped

class YourTable(Base):
    your_column: Mapped[dict[str, Any]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Refactoring Flask app, `Base`s are abstracted away. This worked fine for me, without additional arbitrary types:

```
from typing import Optional
from sqlalchemy import JSON
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column


class SampleTable(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'sampletable'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    data_1: Mapped[dict|list] = mapped_column(type_=JSON, nullable=False)
    data_2: Mapped[Optional[dict|list]] = mapped_column(type_=JSON)
```

`nullable=False` is implied with absent `Optional` type on `data_1` column, but left it to be more explicit.